# Limit of sequences $V(n)$ and $U(n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$U(n)$ and $V(n)$ are sequences. $U(n)> 0$  and   $V(n) >0$ such that: ${V(n+1)\over V(n)}≤ {U(n+1)\over U(n)}$.

Prove that:

1. If $\,\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} V(n)= +\infty\,\,$ then $\,\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}  U(n) = +\infty$
2. If $\,\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} U(n) = 0 \,\, $  then  $\,\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} V(n) = 0$

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Try 'multiplying' the inequality with itself, for example $\frac{V(4)}{V(1)} = \frac{V(4)}{V(3)}\frac{V(3)}{V(2)}\frac{V(2)}{V(1)} \leq \frac{U(4)}{U(3)}\frac{U(3)}{U(2)}\frac{U(2)}{U(1)} = \frac{U(4)}{U(1)}$  This can be generalized.

Comment: Dup: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2077215/

Answer (score 1):

(i) given $M \in \mathbb{R}$ there exist an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that forall $n \geq  \mathbb{N}$ will imply $V(n) > M \frac{1}{U(1)}$. We now take the ratio which will give us

$$\frac{V(n)}{V(1)} \leq\frac{U(n)}{U(1)}$$
which gives us $U(n) \geq M$.  Hence the first one.

(ii) given $\epsilon >0$ there exist an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that forall $n \geq  \mathbb{N}$ will imply $U(n) < \epsilon \frac{1}{V(1)}$. Then 
$$\frac{V(n)}{V(1)} \leq\frac{U(n)}{U(1)}$$ gives us
$$V(n) < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove by induction that $\frac{V_n}{V_1}\le\frac{U_n}{U_1}$. Then, use squeeze theorem to get your result.